# PSCustomObject to concrete type

Tags: powershell

I have a JSON config file:

```json
{
  "name": "foo",
  "bar": {
    "name": "bar"
  }
}
```

I want to read this JSON file and map it to concrete types:

```
class Bar {
    [string] $name
    Bar([string] $name) {
        $this.name = $name
    }
}

class Foo {
    [string] $name
    [Bar] $bar
    Foo([string] $name, [Bar] $bar) {
        $this.name = $name
        $this.bar = $bar
    }
}

$obj = Get-Content "$PSScriptRoot\my.json" | ConvertFrom-Json
$foo = [Foo] $obj
$foo
```

Casting does not work. What would be the correct approach? I'm working on PS 5.1.

Comment: What would be your expected output after creating a new `Foo` object? Try this and see if this is what you want: `[foo]::new($obj.name,[bar]::new($obj.bar))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PowerShell 5.1 we can side-step `ConvertFrom-Json` by calling the JSON serializer directly:

```
# Import the utility module, ensure dependencies loaded, we're gonna use the same serializer as ConvertFrom-Json uses
Import-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility
$null = Get-Command ConvertFrom-Json

$serializer = [System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer]::new()

# Deserialize json to specific target type
$json = Get-Content "$PSScriptRoot\my.json" -Raw
$serializer.Deserialize($json, [Foo])
```

**Note**: this will only work if all the custom types in your object hierarchy have parameterless constructors, so you'll have to refactor your class definitions slightly:

```
class Bar {
    [string] $name
    Bar([string] $name) {
        $this.name = $name
    }

    # Empty ctor for de-serialization
    Bar() {}
}

class Foo {
    [string] $name
    [Bar] $bar
    Foo([string] $name, [Bar] $bar) {
        $this.name = $name
        $this.bar = $bar
    }

    # Empty ctor for de-serialization
    Foo() {}
}
```

Comment: For some reason, instantiating a `[System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer]` doesn't work from the terminal. Neither if I write it to a file and run it from the terminal. But if I run it with the VSCode extension's `PowerShell Integrated Console` it works, strange.

Comment: @Vivere Did you `Import-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility`? :-)

Comment: Yup, I wrote the same code as in your example. Maybe there is something wrong on my side.

Comment: @Vivere Just updated the code, give it another try in a fresh 5.1 session